# Error in model.frame.default : variable lengths differ while running ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

While running ANOVA analysis on a subset of my dataset this error is displayed:

```
  Error in model.frame.default(formula = ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster ==  :   variable lengths differ (found for 'ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster == 3]')
```

Following is my code:

```
     for(a in 1:6){
  for(b in a+1:6){
    result=paste("GDPpercapita  CLusters ",a,"&",b)
    print( result)
    first<-subset(ready,ready$cluster==a)
    second<-subset(ready,ready$cluster==b)
    x<-summary(aov(first$GDPpercapita~second$GDPpercapita))
    print(x)
  }
}
```

And here is a glimpse of my data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb5lP.png)

The error is not because of the loop or because of creating the subsets , as the following code also returns the same error:

```
x<-summary(aov(ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==1]~ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==2]))
print(x)
```

The column cluster is a factor variable.
My objective is to run an ANOVA for every variable(eg GDPpercapita) for all pairs of clusters.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're attempting to use ANOVA like a t-test.

---

`ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==1]` returns a vector of *GDPpercapita* values.

`ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==2]` returns a different vector of *GDPpercapita* values.

You now have two vectors that each hold values of your response variable. When attempting to compare the means of two groups of observed values, a 2-sample test (the t-test is very common) should be used. ANOVA is overkill, and it's really meant for comparing means across many groups.

---

The code

`t.test(ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==1], ready$GDPpercapita[ready$cluster==2])`

would compare the mean *GDPpercapita* between clusters 1 and 2.

Since you are trying to compare the mean *GDPpercapita* across many groups, you could do this for each cluster (commonly referred to as pairwise t-testing). However, you'd have to use a correction (like Bonferroni) which is generally not ideal.

---

Alternatively, ANOVA seems like a good start as long as it's used correctly.

The `aov` function takes a formula as its first parameter. You build the formula using `~` (think of this operator as "by") and `+` (this operator is like "and").

To compare mean *GDPpercapita* of each cluster against each other cluster, you would call:

`aov(GDPpercapita ~ cluster, data = ready)`

Read this as "within the dataset *ready*, compare mean GDPpercapita **BY** every value of the variable *cluster*".

---

You can add more comparisons like this:

`aov(GDPpercapita ~ cluster + CurrentHE, data = ready)`

Read this as "within the dataset *ready*, compare mean GDPpercapita **BY** every value of the variable *cluster* **AND** every value of the variable *CurrentHE*".

---

Note that you may have to do post-hoc testing, as ANOVA will only tell you which included variables (*cluster*, *CurrentHE*, etc) seem to significantly affect the response variable. It won't give specific information like "cluster 1 is associated with a higher *GDPpercapita* than cluster 2". I would recommend reading up on ANOVA and t-testing, as well as how to use them in R.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you